# Why do some of the css properties do not take effect?

Tags: html, css

Why isn't the following style taking effect?

```
.tags a{
  color: red;
}
```

I can force the property by appending `!important` to it.

Code: http://codepen.io/haxan7/pen/QyQNBR

Comment: *"Why doesn't it take effect?"* The answer is [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). In other words, the selector `.theme .content a` is more specific than `.tags a`, thus `color: red` is overridden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of the following two declarations are applicable for the anchor texts.

```
.theme .content a{
  color: green;
}

.tags a{
  color: red;
}
```

color "green" has more specificity then color "red" and thats why "green" is getting applied. Increase the specificity for color "red" then it will get applied.

```
.theme .content .tags a {
 color: red;
}
```

Comment: This solves my problem. But I am wondering if there another way of doing this such that my style applies to the 'tags' div even when they are outside of ".theme .content" divs ?

Answer (score 1):

Because your `.theme .content a` style is setting the a tag color to green.

Change this in your code:

```
.theme .content a{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I know. My question is why the code quoted in the question is not taking effect.